# How can I enable the Keychain Sharing capability in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to share keychain between my app and my app extension,

From the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/keychain-access-groups), it says

> To add this entitlement to your app, enable the Keychain Sharing capability in Xcode.

but I didn't find anything related to **Keychain Sharing capability**.

Anyone knows how to enable it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click the signing & capabilities button. Then click the + (plus) button. From there, add keychain sharing capability

You will also need to set up which apps will share data from the apple developer portal

[image]

Answer (score 5):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH1zi.jpg

You can find the keychain sharing capability
In the project settings...
Signing and capabilities...
Hit the + icon near capability at the top left corner...
Select the keychain sharing

Take a look at the screenshot I provided.

Ziv.